# Intellij code indentation for builders

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-14

Currently if I write use the following builder class Intellij will indent the following way

```
SomeClass.create()
    .someMethod()
    .someOtherMethod();
```

What I would like it to do is indent like this:

```
SomeClass.create()
         .someMethod()
         .someOtherMethod();
```

Does anybody know how to set this up?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

- Code Style => Java => Wrapping and Braces => Chained Method Calls
- Align when multiline

[image]

Produces the following when reformatting source:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, if you have editorconfig setup, you can add the following property to your `.editorconfig` file:

[image]